# Jquery style changes keep reverting after a click

Tags: javascript, css

When I click the filter button the div should go from display none to display block and it does. My issue is that when I click on anything else on the screen, it reverts back to display none. I have an on click function on my filter off button that resets the display back to none and it works as well. It only reverts to display none when I click on my table and it goes away.

I will include my code here

```
// Handles the Filter On
const filterOn = () => {
    $(".filter-alert").css('display', 'block');
    $("#tbl1 td").click(function returnCellValue() {
        let tdText = this.innerHTML;
        $(".filter-alert").css('display', 'block');
        let value;
        let column;


       fnFillGrid();
});    
}


const filterOfff = () => {
    //alert("lc");
    // Need to return SQL string to beginning state/reset values changed by FilterOn
    counter = 0;
    document.getElementById("hiddenFilterTerm").value = '';
    document.getElementById("hiddenFilterCol").value = '';
    $(".filter-alert").css('dipsplay', 'none');
    fnFillGrid();
    $("#tbl1 td").off("click");
    //console.log("Counter: " + counter);
}
```

I just want the style to stay until I call the `filterOfff()` function

Comment: So how is it called?

Comment: I just need my display to stay block; until i call filterOfff() it is reverting back to display none whenever I click anything else that does not call filterOfff()

Comment: We have no clue what is calling filterOfff..... or what is causing it to revert....

Comment: Could you please show your HTML code, whatever is calling filterOn() and filterOff().

Comment: <button id="filter" type="button" onclick="filterOn()">filter</button>              <button id="filterReset" type="button" onclick="filterOfff()">Reset filter</button>

Comment: I posted them above their just buttons with onclick="filterOfff" and onclick="filterOn"